# Cross-domain CSRF

Tags: django, csrf

I've got two different django projects, where one sits on domain A and has a bunch of functionalities (REST among them). Site B is simple and I want to post ajax-forms to site A, but keep csrf security. Is that possible?

Btw sites can share database if necessary.

Comment: Yes, but only if the two are sub-domains of the same domain (or, e.g., one is a subdomain and the other is on the main domain). Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Just created this answer, maybe it is of help to anyone interested in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22584318/889617

Answer (score 3):

I've had a simillar problem and I've managed to solve it in the following way:

1. issue GET request from site B to site A to fetch a form (with csrf field)
2. POST the form back to site A.

The main problem for me was to get cross-site ajax requests to work. To achieve that I've had to configure CORS correctly on the server-side (I've slightly edited this middleware: https://gist.github.com/strogonoff/1369619) and set `xmlHttp.withCredentials = true` (where xmlHttp is my XMLHttpRequest object) in the ajax POST function.

I've tested this solution on two diffenet ports on the same IP address, but I think it should also work cross-domain.

Comment: How do I do this? How to I add this to my Middleware class

Comment: Setting up this middleware is described in comments for this file (https://gist.github.com/strogonoff/1369619#comment-586223).