# Login and register via ajax is secure or not?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My JS Code(Just example, maybe there is some syntax error)

```
$(document).on('click','#btnEdit',function(e){ 
    var id = $("#inp_id").val(), ps = $("#inp_ps");     
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.php',
        data: {act:'#LogIn',id:id,ps:ps},
        success: function(response){
            if($.trim(response) === "success"){
                alert("Login Successful");   
            }
            else{
                alert("Invalid ID or Password");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Inside the php

```
if($_POST[act] == "#LogIn"){
    $userid = Encrypt($_POST[id],$key1);
    $userps = hashPS($_POST[ps],$salt);
    //query...
    if(result > 0){
         $_SESSION['id'] = Encrypt($userid,$key2);
         $_SESSION['token'] = //random code;
    }
}
```

My question:
Is there any way to make the code secure? Because i think the attackers can just write their own script and send data to the php for getting and id.
Or maybe it is just a bad idea using ajax to login and register.

Comment: You can use captcha to protect your site .

Comment: AJAX is no less secure than a form. Hackers can modify form data, too.

Comment: PHP is checking the password, there's nothing attackers can do on the client to get around that.

Comment: Maybe you like the use of [JSON Web Tokens](https://coderwall.com/p/8wrxfw/goodbye-php-sessions-hello-json-web-tokens)

Comment: @JeeHong You are worrying that an attacker will write an script to login, aren't you?

Comment: Apart from Captcha, be sure to use HTTPS to avoid the data to be captured in plain text.

Comment: @iNullPointer i worry about  the attacker trying to "steal" id by writing  a script that can generate random id and password (maybe using looping or wat) and send it to the php until return success

Comment: @Raptor so using https can avoid attacker "steal" id fomr our website? sry for bad english

Comment: @JeeHong Then `CAPTCHA` is the best solution for you. On client side, user need to enter `CAPTCHA` and on server side you need to verify `CAPTCHA`, that is generated at server and displayed to client when login page is loaded, before quarrying `Username` and `Password`. If `CAPTCHA` is not correct you can display message saying `Incorreect CAPTCHA` and `exit`.

Comment: @JeeHong what I mean is, as your HTTP Request & Response are currently unprotected by HTTPS, the contents are in plain text. Basic network packet capture (e.g. using Wireshark) can obtain the response, thus facilitating the bruteforce attack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

Comment: Attackers can write their own script and send data to php for getting an id anyway, there's nothing inherently less secure when logging in via AJAX . If your backend handles the input responsibly and correctly then it doesn't matter if the front-end sent it via AJAX request or scanned Postits attached to an email message.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication/477578#477578)
.

---

**Salting from frontend** mainly aims at protecting privacy of your users.
While **CAPTCHA** aims at verifying your user is a real person but a spider and protecting your server from [DDOS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Distributed_attack).

To guarantee security you need HTTPS. There are potential risks if you implement login service without HTTPS, such as [Man-in-the-Middle-Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). So I have to provide a backend solution here.

As is mentioned by [Raptor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188331/raptor), attackers can still test the password via bruteforce. Yes, indeed. Yet if you choose your encryption algorithm correctly, it will take millions of years to crack a single password.

Besides there is one more attack, named [Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). You have to prevent it by simply introducing a `csrf_token`.

I asked a [question(【django-1.11.3/angular-1.6.4】POST AJAX CSRF verification failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295091/django-1-11-3-angular-1-6-4-post-ajax-csrf-verification-failed) a year ago where you might get some inspiration.

## [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)

#### Installation

```
sudo apt install certbot
```

#### Configuration

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

## Not Certbot

It's sometimes better if you use **OAuth** and make service providers such as Google or Facebook take the responsibility to take care of login security.

Comment: If only HTTPS is used, attackers can still test the password via bruteforce. Incomplete solution.

Comment: Yes I know. Besides there was a Heartbleed Bug within SSL which could lead to serious security risks. But it's what I can do about it so far. You are welcome to improve my answer. Meanwhile I want to point it out that attackers can hijack people in real life and interrogate them to get passwords. Thus the definition and scope of security is important.

Answer (score 3):

The best practices for making it secure are as follows.

1. Implement CSRF token so every request is sent using a CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery). CSRF insures if the request is valid. You may get further details about CSRF implementation from [here](https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3454607)
2. Apply IP check on the server side. Check from which IP the request is coming. You should only accept the requests which are coming from your own server. You can use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] for that purpose
3. Captcha on the client side to protect from BOTS Google recaptcha is best for this. Details are [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html)

If you apply the above you will be secure enough for POST requests.