# error in django and angular 4 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: django, angular

here is my `django` code

I get this error when I test my delete function.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin  is therefore not allowed access. The response had
>   HTTP status code 500.

```
def delete(self):
        ''' Deletes an existed file or folder. '''
        file    = self.request.GET.get('path').lstrip("/")
        path    = os.path.join(self.root,file)
        response = FileManagerResponse(path)
        response.set_response()
        if (self.is_safe_path(path)):
           if os.path.isdir(path):
               shutil.rmtree(path)
           elif os.path.isfile(path):
               os.remove(path)
           return JsonResponse(response.response)
        else:
           return self.fileManagerError(path=file)
```

here is my angular 4 code

```
   deleteFile(id) {
       let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/connectors/python/filemanager?time=1528047056540&mode=delete&path=${id}&_=1528045987217`;
      console.log(url);
      return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

Comment: add response.response['Header'] = 'response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache''

Comment: https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this two post its will be solve your error :

[How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework/35761458)

[AngularJS + Django Rest Framework + CORS ( CSRF Cookie not showing up in client )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931158/angularjs-django-rest-framework-cors-csrf-cookie-not-showing-up-in-client)